# Beamer breaks bibtopic: Error: Found unknown `thebibliography' environment

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm trying to include two separate bibliographies in beamer presentation. I don't cite anything in the presentation, I just want to display (separately) the entire lists included in files: `bib1.bib` and `bib2.bib`.

I tried package `bibtopic` and it works well if I use document class `article`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{bibtopic}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{btSect}{bib1}
\section{Bibliography 1}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}{bib2}
\section{Bibliography 2}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

I build it using this procedure:

```
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex test1
bibtex test2
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```

I switched to document class `beamer` (not changed anything else, I only removed .aux files etc. for the clear situation):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{bibtopic}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{btSect}{bib1}
\section{Bibliography 1}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}{bib2}
\section{Bibliography 2}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I run first `pdflatex test.tex` and I'm getting error:

```
! Package bibtopic Error: Found unknown `thebibliography' environment.
```

This is an error, not a warning, so it stops the compilation process. I tried other solutions to this error message included on tex.stackexchange, but the error persisted. I think it's a bit different situation than described there, since it works for `article`.

I also tried switching to `biblatex`, but it shows other error (when I issue `pdflatex test.tex` after `biber test`):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you indicated that you tried to switch to `biblatex`. With `biblatex` you can use `refsection`s -- however they can not span more than one frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}  
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{knuth:ct}
        \printbibliography
    \end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{westfahl:space}
        \printbibliography
    \end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```